# Get bit-version of OS using javascript

Tags: javascript, operating-system, bit

How to detect bit-version of operating system using javascript (32 or 64)? It can be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect 64-bit or 32-bit Windows from User Agent or Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741933/detect-64-bit-or-32-bit-windows-from-user-agent-or-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using `window.navigator.platform`

Comment: not sure you.I just grab the thing here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.platform