# x64 or x32 with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect 64-bit or 32-bit Windows from User Agent or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741933/detect-64-bit-or-32-bit-windows-from-user-agent-or-javascript)

I just downloaded itunes from the Apple website and when I clicked download it automatically downloaded the x64 version as I am on a 64 bit machine. Does anyone know how the website is able to detect what architecture I am using? Is it and can it be done with javascript? If so how?

Comment: In a browser, if you run `window.navigator.userAgent` in a console like Chrome's, you'll see your browser is tattling on you. Many browsers also send this to the server in a header.

Comment: Some hints must be available from `navigator.userAgent` string.

Comment: For instance: `User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser sends a [user agent string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) to the server in every request. It contains some information about the browser and the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to check what user-agent string your browser sent the website you are visiting right now, enter this into your browsers navigation bar:

```
javascript:alert(window.navigator.userAgent);
```