# Reliability of navigator.platform

Tags: javascript, http-headers

How reliable is the JavaScript property 'navigator.platform' and under what circumstances might it return a wrong operating system?

Comment: theres some tests made here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741933/detect-64-bit-or-32-bit-windows-from-user-agent-or-javascript you probably should tap into the user agent for more reliable results about the operating system.

Comment: Unless your code is privileged (chrome or at least has the UniversalBrowserRead privilege), it may get the value of the general.platform.override preference instead of the true platform.