# Browser detection script gives a wrong bit for navigator.platform

Tags: javascript

I ran the below code in jsfiddle using chrome browser

```
console.log(navigator.appCodeName + ' - ' + navigator.appName + ' - ' + navigator.appVersion + ' - ' + navigator.userAgent + ' - ' + navigator.platform);
```

and got the below result

> Mozilla - Netscape - 5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36 - Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36 - Win32

Things are fine except for

```
navigator.platform // this gave the output as Win32
```

whereas my OS is 64-bit.  When it says platform, the 64 bit OS should indicated it as 64 bit only, but here its different. Can anyone explain ?

Thanks

Comment: Chrome is 32 bit. That may be part of the issue.

Comment: @colecmc - that mean's navigator.platform returns the bit value of browser rather than OS, thanks so far i thought it's about OS

Comment: You can check if you have a 32 bit version of Chrome in the `chrome://chrome/` settings

Comment: User agent strings are not controlled by any standard, they can be anything the authors want. You should not rely on information they provide (as you've discovered). There are [*databases*](https://www.google.com.au/search?rls=en&q=user+agent+string+database) that might narrow the odds.

Comment: `WOW64` in the user agent indicates 64-bit windows.

Comment: @jfriend00 - it gives raise to another question - should we need to follow the agent navigator.appName to get the bit info of OS? kindly clarify

Comment: @colecmc hope your tried to type chrome://version/ - and it says mine is m(32-bit)

Comment: As far as I know, there is no specific standard for identifying 32-bit vs. 64-bit platforms from the user agent string, so if you were going to use that for it, you would just have to examine existing behaviors on the browsers you want to support and code for what they do.  It begs the question of why you need to know?

Comment: Seems like this might be a dup: [Detect 64-bit or 32-bit Windows from User Agent or Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741933/detect-64-bit-or-32-bit-windows-from-user-agent-or-javascript)