# Why does window.navigator.platform return WIN32 on a 64-bit machine?

Tags: javascript, window

I need to be able to determine which version of Windows (32-bit or 64-bit) a user is running. My computer is very definitely 64-bit:

[image]

But when I try using `window.navigator.platform` in the console in either Firefox, Chrome, or IE11, it returns WIN32.

Can anyone give me an idea of why this is happening? If this isn't an accurate way of determining OS platform, what is? (This has to be done client-side.)

Comment: Are these 32 or 64 bit browsers ? Having a 64 bit OS does not necessarily mean you have an identical browser. The Useragent should convey information about the operating system

Comment: Is it detecting your OS bit-ness or just the Browser bit-ness? Is it possible the Browser itself is 32-bit running on a 64-bit OS? Have you searched? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741933/detect-64-bit-or-32-bit-windows-from-user-agent-or-javascript

Comment: @mrunion - yes, I've searched. That's the post I got the `window.navigator.platform` from. I've also tried the `cpuClass` property, but it returns "undefined" in every browser.

Comment: cpuClass only works on IE (http://help.dottoro.com/ljcsokrr.php).

Comment: @mrunion - thanks. I wasn't able to quickly find any documentation on that one.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this solution can help [link to mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/platform#Usage_notes)