# How can I check the type of OS(32bit or 64bit)? ASP.NET vNext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have to show 5 buttons: Win32, Win64, Linux32, Linux64, MacOs.
I have to decorate one button. Decorated button depends of user's os and 32-bit or 64-bit.
How can I do it?
I use ASP.NET vNext. Also we can use JS, but ASP.NET vNext in priority.

Comment: Try and parse it from the useragent string?

Comment: That's good idea, but I can't get a bit of OS. I have to understand: is it x32 or x64?.

Comment: This might help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741933/detect-64-bit-or-32-bit-windows-from-user-agent-or-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741933/detect-64-bit-or-32-bit-windows-from-user-agent-or-javascript)