# Detecting whether browser is 32 or 64 bit with Javascript

Tags: javascript, browser

How can I use Javascript to detect whether the user's browser is 32 or 64 bit? I read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741933/detect-64-bit-or-32-bit-windows-from-user-agent-or-javascript) but it only says how to detect the version of a Windows OS, not the browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect 64-bit or 32-bit Windows from User Agent or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741933/detect-64-bit-or-32-bit-windows-from-user-agent-or-javascript)

Comment: It's not. That article discusses how to detect the version of a Windows OS, not the browser.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't do this with client running JavaScript.** The best you could do is, as you've said, look at the user-agent string and see what the OS is using, but even that isn't reliable as user-agent strings can easily be changed.

You would need code running at the OS level to get this data.

Comment: OP wants to know about the browser, not the OS, which these days, can be assumed to be 64bit...

Comment: @dandavis Read my answer. I specifically mentioned exactly that!