# Firefox 32-bit does not fire ondevicechange event

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc, getusermedia

I'm having trouble using the MediaDevices.ondevicechange event in Firefox (77.0) 32-Bit Version.
The event is not fired at all. In Firefox (77.0) 64-Bit the code works as expected. My machine is a 64-Bit Windows 10 desktop computer.

The example on the [official mozilla site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/ondevicechange) doesn't work either - it doesn't detect device changes in 32-Bit Firefox.

Anyone else experiencing this issue? Is this a bug or the expected behavior?

Is there a way to differentiate between Firefox 32- and 64-Bit with javascript? I don't see a way to do this with just feature detection, as they behave the same (code wise).
If yes i could at least implement some kind of fallback.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For extensive discussion of way to differentiate between 32 and 64-Bit question, see:

[Detect 64-bit or 32-bit Windows from User Agent or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741933/detect-64-bit-or-32-bit-windows-from-user-agent-or-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for your response,
it seems that detecting 64 vs 32-Bit Firefox is not possible, just for the system. The problem with this is, that you can install a Firefox 32-Bit on a 64-Bit machine. In that case the detection would fail.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference between the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Firefox when it comes to the `devicechange` event.

My guess is you're running with different profiles in the two versions, and you've granted persistent **camera or microphone permission** to your site in one and not the other.

Firefox has a [bug](https://bugzil.la/1397977) which limits the `devicechange` event to pages that are either already actively using the camera or microphone at the moment, or have been granted persistent camera or microphone permission (you've checked `☑ Remember this decision`) in the past.

You can test it out in Firefox [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jib1/LbtxeLvw/show):

1. Insert or remove a USB or bluetooth camera → nothing happens
2. Click the `Start camera!` button and share a camera.
3. Insert or remove a USB or bluetooth camera → *"device change!"* is logged

This bug will hopefully be addressed soon.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However  the difference in behavior is a thing:

I used two clean installations 32-Bit and 64-Bit each in a private tab, one after another.
On the Mozilla page i click "start", then accept the audio permission dialog (there is no remember this decision checkbox on the Mozilla ondevicechange page for me).

If I unplug my microphone, it takes some seconds, but in 64-Bit the microphone disappears from the list of audio devices. In 32-Bit, no matter how long i wait, the microphone stays in the list.

Comment: I tried again using the fiddle you posted, with the same results. Firefox 64-bit, after accepting and pressing start, shows the "device change!" output, Firefox 32-Bit does not.